# How to pass a dynamic value from parent to child in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-state

So my App.js file looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import './App.css';
import Header from "./components/pages/Header";
import NAV from "./NAV";
import Trees from "./components/tree";


function App() {
 
    
      const [inputField , setInputField] = useState({
        first_name: 'Phyag_NZFS3770'
    })
   
    const inputsHandler = (e) =>{
        setInputField( {[e.target.name]: e.target.value} )
    }

    const submitButton = () =>{
        alert(inputField.first_name)
        

    }
  


return(
<div className="App">
      <NAV genomename={inputField.first_name}/> //this can't be done as the prop value is undefined
      <Header title="EumicrobeDB"/>
      <h3 style={{ textAlign:"left" }}> Organism List </h3>  
        <div> <Trees /> </div>
          <div>
            <input 
            type="text" 
            name="first_name" 
            onChange={inputsHandler} 
            placeholder="enter the organism id" 
            value={inputField.first_name}/>
            <button onClick={submitButton}>Submit Now</button> 
        </div>
    </div>
    )

    
  } 
export default App;
```

Can anyone please **modify** the code to pass {inputField.first_name} as prop value to my function called NAV? I am in an absolute fix..I am a biologist who is new to React; who has to meet a deadline

Comment: Looks fine to me, the default value in `useState` should make sure neither `inputField` nor `inputField.first_name` is undefined. Can you add the error message you're getting?

Comment: *"this can't be done as the prop value is undefined"* How do you know the prop value is `undefined`? How do you access the prop in your `NAV` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can pass data from parent component to child as a `props`.

**Example**

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Header = ({ title }) => {
  return <React.Fragment>Hello, {title}</React.Fragment>;
};

function App() {
  const [inputField, setInputField] = useState({
    first_name: "Phyag_NZFS3770"
  });

  const inputsHandler = (e) => {
    console.log([e.target.name] , e.target.value);
    setInputField({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const submitButton = () => {
    alert(inputField.first_name);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header title={inputField.first_name} />
      <h3 style={{ textAlign: "left" }}> Organism List </h3>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="first_name"
          onChange={inputsHandler}
          placeholder="enter the organism id"
          value={inputField.first_name}
        />
        <button onClick={submitButton}>Submit Now</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in this component looks fine as-is. Make sure you're accessing `props.genomename` and not `props.first_name` in the NAV component.

If you're planning to add more input fields, I'd also suggest you change the inputHandler function to merge with the previous state, rather than replacing it entirely:

```
const inputsHandler = (e) => {
    setInputField({ ...inputField, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}
```